# CSS grid expand a single column in a row

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have CSS grid with a single row. One of the columns has more content than the others and I would like to expand it vertically without expanding the others.

I have tried using `grid-template-rows: auto` but that expands all the columns. I have also tried using `display: flex` and `flex-grow: 1` with no luck.

I would like the second column to be longer than the others, but actually it is the same height

[image: actual]

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 2rem;
  grid-template-areas: "first second third";
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: first;
  border-style: solid;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: second;
  border-style: solid;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: third;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<span class="item1">item 1</span>
<span class="item2">item 2<br><br>expanded</span>
<span class="item3">item 3</span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/679y4d0z/

Comment: is this what you try to do ? https://jsfiddle.net/z8v6nrqw/

Comment: Yes the `margin-bottom: auto` and `minmax` function solves my problem thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have different heights for the same row.

How would you target the different areas of the row? It doesn't work.

A row has a uniform height.

You can, however, adjust the height of grid items in a row.

Because the default height for grid items is `stretch` (giving them the full height of the row), simply override that setting with `align-items: start` (causing them to shrink-to-fit the content).

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: start;
}

span {
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<span class="item1">item 1</span>
<span class="item2">item 2<br><br>expanded</span>
<span class="item3">item 3</span>
```

Comment: "You can't have different heights for the same row." - agreed, but you *can* use a rowspan (via `grid-row-start`  and `grid-row-end`) on varying items to achieve the same _visual_ result.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest looking into Bootstrap. I have a hard time with CSS changes but Bootstrap really helps! They have a grid system and it makes it super easy to change sizes like you're looking to do

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, there is a requirement that I cannot use third party libraries

Comment: This does not actually answer the user's question. Suggesting a framework would only be relevant in a much broader context. It is not helpful when the questioner has a very specific technical question about something in the CSS standard.

Comment: I believe it perfectly answers the question. It's unfortunate that third party libraries are off the able for the user, but had they been on the table I believe using Bootstrap would be the perfect answer